# Where to put maven generated webapp artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, swagger-maven-plugin

I'm using the swagger maven plugin to generate my swagger.json file. I want this to be available as a static resource in the webapp (src/main/webapp).

In the example on the github page they configure it like this.

```
<swaggerDirectory>generated/swagger-ui</swaggerDirectory>
```

I can't see how this would be useful as it's not in the webapp folder. I guess you'd have to manually copy it somewhere useful but what's the point in maven if it's not automated.

I've configured it like this in my project.

```
<swaggerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/swagger</swaggerDirectory>
```

This allows me to access the file both during development (as an eclipse project) and when deployed (as a built war file).

The question is whether it's ok to pop generated artifacts in the usual src/main folder?

I have generated code from jaxb but that goes into a generated-sources folder in the target folder. This is then added as a source folder in eclipse and maven knows to add these classes to the build.

I basically just want to check I haven't comitted a maven faux pas by dumping my generated code in src/main/webapp. I know I'll have to gitignore this file.

Answer (score 1):

You could place the generated files in a directory such as `target/generated-webapp`. Then use the [resource plugin to copy](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) all the other files from `src/main/webbpp` to `target/generated-webapp`. And finally point the [war plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html) to `target/generated-webapp` as it's [warSourceDirectory](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against putting generated code into src/main - which would be committed to source control. Besides, in your case the file itself is getting generated by a maven plugin - which will run when you build your project.

Rather use the resources, war, assembly... plugins to copy the file into your built war.

Comment: It won't be committed to source control if I gitignore it. Also, it is desirable to be able to use this during development so I need a way for it to be part of the build but also accessible when I'm running it as an eclipse project.

Comment: When you say run as an eclipse project - are you using jetty/tomcat plugins? Since these can be configured to run base on the generated war in the target folder. Anyways we are arguing about best practices - which may not suit your particular case

Comment: It's just an eclipse project that gets created by importing maven project from SCM. So the project structure is based on the pom. Then to test/run it it's added as a web project to a tomcat server setup in eclipse. It's not a bundled server. Best practice is one thing but I can't be the only person using this plugin, I just want to make sure it will work without any gotchas.